# Automate Multiline Alignment in Gregorio for Litanies and Verses

Tags: macros, luatex, tabbing, gregorio

I'm trying to use Gregorio to create a multiline file in using Latex.  I have successfully compiled scores using my system, so in terms of a working Gregorio install, things are working fine.

In trying to find the solution to creating a multiline score, I came across [this "how to"](http://gregorio-project.github.io/tips/litany.html). I copied the source into the various files and attempted to compile, and ran into an error that I can't figure out.  I've done some macro programming in LaTeX, but am not really up on the difference between LuaLaTeX and all the other compilers which are available.  I believe this is relevant because part of the output log says that "\pdfsavepos" is not supported".  Here is the output:

```
 This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 system commands enabled.
(./litany.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luatex-def/luatex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty(using 
write cache: /Users/myusername/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gen
eric)(using read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic 
/Users/myusername/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.633 seconds)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luamplib/luamplib.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-main.tex
(litany.gaux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-spaces.t
ex)(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts
/otl/greciliae.luc)(load luc: /Users/myusername/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-var
/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/greciliae.luc)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-chars.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-signs.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-syllable
.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-symbols.
tex(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts
/otl/greextra.luc)(load luc: /Users/myusername/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/greextra.luc))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gsp-default.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/gregoriotex/gregoriotex-nabc.tex
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-savepos.sty

/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-savepos.sty:59: Pack
age zref Error: \pdfsavepos is not supported.
(zref)                It is provided by pdfTeX (1.40) or XeTeX.

See the zref package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.59 }{}
      %
? 
Process aborted
```

I believe it has something to do with the fact that Gregorio requires the use of LuaLaTeX, and \pdfsavepos isn't supported there.  Any ideas as to a fix?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should try with `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` at the very beginning of your document

Comment: that's odd, if that error is on line 59 it should mean that you have the latest version which means that line 54 (of zref-savepos.sty) should be `\let\pdfsavepos          \savepos` which should make it work in lualatex without `luatex85` package....

Comment: Can you supply a test file that generates the error (it dies loading packages so the test file would not need to be very long, but I tried loading gregoriotex and zref and it worked for me)

Comment: I can try.  I've uploaded the salient Gregorio files to a drop box folder.  (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jltb7f75b02z7q7/AAAtQnPk2F3zYJXfgl_5CFoAa?dl=0)

Comment: I added the files I generated from the tutorial, as well as some test documents (labeled "test").  As soon as I comment the \usepackage{pdfsavepos} line the document will compile.  If it's left in, the same error pops up.

Comment: I went through the TeXLive utility and reinstalled the oberdiek packages.  That solved the problem.  Must have been an outdated package in there.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by updating the TeX system

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to make sure that the supporting packages were up to date.  I updated the TeXLive Utility and that did not solve the problem; however, when I went into the packages and reinstalled "oberdiek" the files in the link worked just fine!